# Set file-level option to scalapb project

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'm using ScalaPB (version 0.11.1) and plugin sbt-protoc (version 1.0.3) to try to compile an old project with ProtocolBuffers in Scala 2.12. Reading the [documentation](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations/#file-level-options), I want to set the file property `preserve_unknown_fields` to `false`. But my question is, where? Where do I need to set this flag? On the .proto file?

I've also tried to include the flag as a package-scoped option by creating a package.proto file next to my other .proto file, with the following content (as it is specified [here](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations/#package-scoped-options)):

```
import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";

package eur.astrata.eu.bigdata.tpms.protobuf;

option (scalapb.options) = {
  preserve_unknown_fields: false
};
```

But when trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
[libprotobuf WARNING T:\src\github\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\parser.cc:648] No syntax specified for the proto file: package.proto. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
scalapb/scalapb.proto: File not found.
package.proto:1:1: Import "scalapb/scalapb.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

I've also tried with `syntax = "proto3";` at the beginning but it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be in `src/main/protobuf`

Comment: @mfirry Thanks. The files are already on that location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations/#getting-started-with-scalapbproto):

> If you are using sbt-protoc and importing protos like
> scalapb/scalapb.proto, or common protocol buffers like
> google/protobuf/wrappers.proto:
>
> Add the following to your build.sbt:
>
> `libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"`
>
> This tells sbt-protoc to extract protos from this jar (and all its dependencies,
> which includes Google's common protos), and make them available in the
> include path that is passed to protoc.

It is important to add that by setting `preserve_unknown_fields` to false you are turning off a protobuf feature that could prevent data loss when different parts of a distributed system are not running the same version of the schema.